# Best way of client server communication in Java

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming, client-server

I am building an application where in the requirement is that, there is a main server, which will send signal to client server, based on this signal the client performs certain action and send back the response to the main server. Here there will be only one main server and can be multiple client servers. At a given time the main server can send multiple signal to multiple clients.
I am presently planning to do this using socket programming in Java using two ports. Do let me know the best way of achieving this? and also do we have any good existing API's that can be used?

Comment: Have you heard of [websockets](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jsr356-1937161.html)? Perhaps that is not the thing for you, but it seems like that is something you would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at RMI: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/ If you want something based on sockets/TCP/UDP/etc, writing something with Netty may be good solution -> http://netty.io/ (they have useful examples).

I would also recommend to consider plain Java Sockets if planned communication beetween server and clients is not comlex and you do not need all this stuff which is provided by libraries like Netty.

Comment: Thanks for the details Mateusz. I wanted to know if Netty and RMI are opensource? and also the communication is between client and server is going to be scheduled. Here the server is a web application, but the client is not going to be web based, it is just going to perform the action needed by the server and will return back the details, it can be a script in Java or in shell or anything.

Comment: Netty is open-source and RMI is build in Java EE, so you should not worry about licenses. If communication must be scheduled, you must implement it separately. I can recommend [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) (opensource) for it. It has much features, but it is quite simple to use. No matter that server will be web application and client something else. If you provide proper communication interface, this will not be a problem. I used Netty to communicate between Java server application and many other workers written in Java, C and Python.